# wp.media javascript issue with on select

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, javascript, uploads

I'm not an expert on JS so I faced a problem in my plugin that I working on, the problem is I made a custom repeater field with uploader using **wp.media** for each field as you will see at the code below:

```
var mediaClientUploader;

// background
$(document).on('click', '.upload_client_logo', function(e) {

    // blocking
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);
    var  myInput = $this.prev('input');

    //alert(myInput.data('repeat-count'));

    if ( mediaClientUploader ) {
        mediaClientUploader.open();

        return;
    }

    mediaClientUploader = wp.media.frames.file_frame = wp.media({

        title: 'Upload Picture',
        button: {
            text: 'Choose Picture'
        },

        multiple: false

    });

    console.log(mediaClientUploader);

    mediaClientUploader.on('select', function () {


        attachment = mediaClientUploader.state().get('selection').toJSON();

        myInput.val(attachment.url);

    });

    mediaClientUploader.open();

});
```

The problem is this specific part

```
mediaClientUploader.on('select', function () {


        attachment = mediaClientUploader.state().get('selection').toJSON();

        myInput.val(attachment.url);

    });
```

it's just running for one time, I mean with that is for the first select will append the URL over and over for the first input I choose!!

I know this problem I can solve it by **$(document).on("select", "#div", function)** but I don't know how I can use this approach with wp.media or my var **mediaClientUploader**

Comment: on `mediaClientUploader.on('select', function ()` , use `insert` instead of `select`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem :"D it was this part of the code

```
 if ( mediaClientUploader ) {
    mediaClientUploader.open();

    return;
}
```

it stops my select event functionality after the first click so I just delete it and everything is fine